# Selecting distinct coordinate pair in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I have a PostGIS table containing four columns:

x, y, k_x, k_y

Each row represents a relationship between two points.
Many of the relationships are duplicates albeit in the other direction, like so:

```
x  |  y  |  k_x  |  k_y
-----------------------
1  |  2  |   3   |   4
-----------------------
3  |  4  |   1   |   2
```

I'd like to create a table with a unique ID per relation, regardless of direction. So in the example above both those rows would share the same ID.

Selecting by Distinct gives me the unique *directed* relations, which wont suffice.

I tried this query to at least identify unique rows, but it's not completing within a reasonable time frame so I think I'm missing something there:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
    pairs as a
INNER JOIN
    pairs as b
ON
    true
    AND ((a.x != b.k_x) AND (a.y != b.k_y))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the distinct pairs, one need to compare the smallest and greatest values for each **set** of coordinates.

You can compare multiple values together by adding parentheses around several field ->`(x,y)`

```
WITH pairs(x,y,k_x,k_y) AS (
  values (1,2,3,4),
         (3,4,1,2),
         (1,4,3,2),
         (1,2,5,6))
SELECT LEAST((x,y),(k_x,k_y)), GREATEST((x,y),(k_x,k_y)) 
FROM pairs
GROUP BY LEAST((x,y),(k_x,k_y)), GREATEST((x,y),(k_x,k_y));
 least | greatest
-------+----------
 (1,2) | (3,4)
 (1,2) | (5,6)
 (1,4) | (3,2)
```